# Create a pie chart to get the utilization of the rack system

Tags: anylogic

How can I get the utilization of my rack system. I tried the function PRD.capacity() - PRD.size() but it only changes the amount when pallets were stored into my racks but not the percentage of the reserved and the free capacity, also not the colors (don't know how I can create the different colors for reserved and free racks)

[piechart_simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ebIQ.png)

[piechart_function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH7v2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SOF.

> How can I get the utilization of my rack system.

Simply use `myRackSystem.statsUtilization.xxx` where xxx gives you various handles on the statistics collected as below:
[image]

For more advanced statistics, you will need to collect those yourself. Lots of example models show you how to use Dataset and Histogram objects to plot stuff in pie charts, check those as well :-)